# how to assign select result to variable c#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2013

i'm making GUI for a database (school project) and I have following problem - when i try to assign resul from select statement to variable i have strange error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

this is my code:

```
                    string sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Car WHERE Make = '@CarID' AND Model = '@CarID2');";
                    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(sql2, sqlconn);
                    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarID", model_cbo);
                    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarID2", make_cbo);
                    string CarID = cmd3.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

I've looking for the solution for a long time, but haven't found anything, so please help

This is my code for connection with DB:

```
    public CarSpec()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connectDB();
        this.conn = new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=HENIU;Initial Catalog=ServiceStation; Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        conn.Open();
    }
    public void connectDB()
    {
        sqlconn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HENIU; Initial Catalog=ServiceStation; Integrated Security=TRUE;");
        sqlconn.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    }
```

Comment: The exception is telling you the exact problem, your SQL statement syntax is incorrect, you have a trailing `)` that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Look at your SQL statement again, the error is in it and the error message gives you everything you need.

Comment: Have you considered that "Additional information: Incorrect syntax near ')'." is actually useful information? Why do you have `)` in your SQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems in your code:

- There is a parenthesys not needed at the end of the WHERE clause
- The parameters should be free from the single quotes. (Otherwise the will be treated as string literals)
- The ExecuteScalar returns just a the first column of the first row.
  You cannot be certain that this will be the carID.

Use instead

```
string sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Car WHERE Make = @CarID AND Model = @CarID2";
SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(sql2, sqlconn);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarID", model_cbo);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarID2", make_cbo);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd3.ExecuteReader()
if(reader.Read())
{
    int carID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CarID"]);
}
```

Here I am assuming that a carID is a number and not a string (as it should be). However, if it is a string then you could change the line to

```
 string carID = reader["CarID"].ToString();
```